# Javascript decimal precision inside the function has long precision

Tags: javascript

```js
var t = 0.2 + 0.3
console.log(t);

function myFunction() {
  var x = 0.2 + 0.1;
  console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

**Output:** 0.5

**After clicking button output is:** 0.30000000000000004

I'm curious why it behave differently inside the function and outside the function and also why precision is so big?

Comment: http://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with whether the code is inside or outside the function.